# Is my code stopping NON duplicates from being entered into a table?

Tags: json, sql-server

I am developing an application to use JSON data that is regularly topped up with fresh JSON data via a Delphi application I'm also writing. I have a SP to import this information, copied here:

```
USE [CMUtility]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Import_CareAlerts]    Script Date: 13/02/2020 09:08:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- ===========================================================================================
-- Author:      Me
-- Create date: 02/12/2019
-- ===========================================================================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Import_CareAlerts] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @home_name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FILEPATH NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @FILEPATH = 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\CMServer\Win32\Debug\CareAlertsReport-'+@home_name+'.json'
    SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX) SELECT @JSON = BULKCOLUMN FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@FILEPATH+''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j; '


    IF OBJECT_id(QuoteName('CareAlerts-'+@home_name)) IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL +'BEGIN TRY INSERT INTO '+QuoteName('CareAlerts-'+@home_name)+' SELECT j2.*, j3.Day, j4.*, ''0'' as Deleted '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL + 'BEGIN TRY SELECT j2.*, j3.Day, j4.*, ''0'' as Deleted INTO '+QuoteName('CareAlerts-'+@home_name)
    END

    set @SQL = @SQL + '
        FROM OPENJSON(@JSON) 
        WITH
        (   
            ........)STUFF EDITED HERE BECAUSE NOT IMPORTANT
        )

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH PRINT ''Duplicate records attempted: ''+ERROR_MESSAGE( ) --catches error message and adds to Messages, without tripping up the code
    END CATCH

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc --checks to see if there is already a unique constraint and adds if necessary
    inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cu 
        on cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    where 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = ''UNIQUE''
    and tc.TABLE_NAME = '+QuoteName('CareAlerts-'+@home_name, char(39))+'
    and cu.COLUMN_NAME like ''%Day%'') = 0  
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE '+QuoteName('CareAlerts-'+@home_name)+' ADD CONSTRAINT U_NAMECAs UNIQUE(Day, CareNote, AlertTypeEnum, OccurredWhen, ConnectionID); 
    END'
```

I then run this in order to import the JSON. However, there will be occasion where there will be some duplicate rows in addition to non-duplicated information, but my code is basically stopping either of them being entered.

I'm assuming there is a more elegant way of accomplishing this without the need to rewrite all my code, but I am still new(ish) to this and could use some help. I've read that maybe a temp table would work to put the fresh import in, and then do a distinct insert, but I'm not sure how it would work for MY code.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Ant

Answer (score 0):

So I added did a few things:

1) Changed the top of the SP to import everything to a temporary holding table (and removing the bit about insert or select into)

2) Once at the end of my import, added the following.

```
SET @SQL1 = 'INSERT INTO '+QuoteName('Residents-'+@home_name) +'
SELECT * FROM [ResidentsDUMP] RD
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '+QuoteName('Residents-'+@home_name)+' R
WHERE RD.PersonID = R.PersonID)'
```

Seemed very simple to do, yet I couldn't work out why the extra resident I'd placed in the JSON file to test still wasn't showing...then I realised I had left the PersonID value the same for both the original and extra resident, so of course it wouldn't show. Idiot!

Anyway, I'm sure there are plenty of other ones like this on here, but that was my experience.

Cheers